# Sorting an array of arrays by the child array's length?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

What's the best way in PHP to sort an array of arrays based on array length?

e.g.

```
$parent[0] = array(0, 0, 0);
$parent[2] = array("foo", "bar", "b", "a", "z");
$parent[1] = array(4, 2);

$sorted = sort_by_length($parent)

$sorted[0] = array(4, 2);
$sorted[1] = array(0, 0, 0);
$sorted[2] = array("foo", "bar", "b", "a", "z");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
function sort_by_length($arrays) {
    $lengths = array_map('count', $arrays);
    asort($lengths);
    $return = array();
    foreach(array_keys($lengths) as $k)
        $return[$k] = $arrays[$k];
    return $return;
}
```

Note that this function will preserve the numerical keys. If you want to reset the keys, wrap it in a call to [array_values()](http://www.php.net/array_values).

Answer (score 3):

I'm upvoting Peter's but here's another way, I think:

```
function cmp($a1, $a2) {
    if (count($a1) == count($a2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (count($a1) < count($a2)) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: This worked but did not maintain the keys.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I was able to preserve the keys by using uasort instead of usort.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `usort` function:

```
function sortByLength( $arr1, $arr2 )
{
    $c1 = count($arr1);
    $c2 = count($arr2);

    return $c1 < $c2 ? -1 : $c1 == $c2 ? 0 : 1;
}

usort($initial_array,'sortByLength');
```

**edited to respect parameters-by-reference; it's the same answer as @david, anyway**

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` compares by size before quality.

Because all of your rows have the same flat structure, `sort()` will sort ascending by row size, sort ascending by first elements, then the next elements, etc.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0kR6f))

```
$parent[0] = array(0, 0, 0);
$parent[2] = array("foo", "bar", "b", "a", "z");
$parent[1] = array(4, 2);
$parent[5] = array(11, 2);
$parent[3] = array(1, 21);
$parent[4] = array(11, 1);

sort($parent);
var_export($parent);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 21,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 11,
    1 => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 11,
    1 => 2,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar',
    2 => 'b',
    3 => 'a',
    4 => 'z',
  ),
)
```

This performs identically to this use of `array_multisort()` with iterated calls of `count`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kD9H6))

```
array_multisort(array_map('count', $parent), $parent);
var_export($parent);
```

Using `usort()` is different if only sorting on the counts because in modern PHP it will leave tied comparisons in their original position : ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sO7X5))

```
usort($parent, fn($a, $b) => count($a) <=> count($b));
var_export($parent);
```